# Can't call validation methods in Java

Tags: java

I have this problem, I created two methods that validate the users input. Then I am trying to get their input to validate before the rest of the program is run. It won't work and I can't find any thing online that will help.

I did it in another program the exact same way, yet it won't work in this one. Any help would be much appreciated.

(the main section is commented out because I was trying to get it run)...

```
    import java.util.*;




public class GuessingGame {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    int answer;
    int tries = 0;
    answer = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);



    System.out.println("Welcome to the Guess the Number Game ");
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ \n");
    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1-100 ");
    System.out.println("Try to guess it! ");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";

while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))    
{



        int guess = getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter number: ", 0, 100);




        /**

        if (guess == answer) 
        {
            System.out.println("Your guess is correct! Congratulations!");
        }
        else if (guess > answer + 10)
            { System.out.println("Your guess was way too high");
            tries++;
            }

        else if (guess < answer)
            { System.out.println("Your guess was too low. Try again. ");
            tries++;
            }

        else if (guess > answer)
            {System.out.println("Your guess was too high. Try again.");
            tries++;
            }



                System.out.println("The number was " + answer + " !");
                System.out.println("You guessed it in " + tries + " tries");

                    if (tries < 2)
                        {System.out.println("That was lucky!");
                        }

                    if (tries >=2 && tries <=4)
                        {System.out.println("That was amazing!");
                        }

                    if (tries > 4 && tries <= 6)
                        {System.out.println("That was good.");
                        }

                    if (tries >= 7 && tries <=7)
                        {System.out.println("That was OK. ");
                        }

                    if (tries > 7 && tries < 10)
                        { System.out.println("That was not very good. ");
                        }

                    if (tries >= 10)
                        {System.out.println("This just isn't your game. ");
                        }
                **/ 

                      //ask if they want to continue
                    System.out.println("\n Continue (y/n)? ");
                    choice = sc.next();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println();

    }

    //print out thank you message
    System.out.println("Thanks for finding the common divisor ");
    sc.close();
}

public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean valid = false;

    while(valid == false);
    {   
        System.out.println(prompt);
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
        {
            i = sc.nextInt();
            valid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number... ");
        }
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    return i;

}








public static int getIntWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt, int min, int max)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean valid = false;

    while (valid == false)
    {
        i = getInt(sc, prompt);
        if (i <= min || i >= max)
            System.out.println("Number must be between 1-100 ");
        else
            valid = true;
    }
    return i;
}
```

}

Comment: What problem are you facing??

Answer (score 4):

In the method `getInt()`, this will result in an infinite loop:

```
boolean valid = false;

while(valid == false);
{
```

due to trailing semi-colon: remove it. The trailing-semi colon makes the `while` equivalent to:

```
while (valid == false) {}
```

which means the intended loop body is never executed and the value of `valid` is never changed.

Comment: @hmjd.. You actually noticed that?? Wow.

Comment: wow ya thanks a bunch!  I spent a couple hours trying to figure out what the problem was...  it's always something like that..

Answer (score 1):

Although your problem has been solved, I would like to point a few things about your code..

First of all, your code has so much of duplicacy..

Your method: -  **`getIntWithinRange`** is just delegating your request to another method **`getInt`**, which I think is useless.. 
What all you have in **`getInt`** method, you can simply move it to **`getIntWithinRange`** method.. That way you won't be creating `2 boolean` variables, `2 while loops`, and so many repeated code..

Also, you don't need to check boolean value like: -

```
while (valid == false)   // Not needed
while (!valid)      // is enough
```

Also, you can have your `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` as your instance variable.. You don't need to define it in all the methods you are reading user input.. And actually you are not.. You are just duplicating it..

**In your commented code: -**

```
if (tries >= 7 && tries <=7)
```

is equivalent to: -

```
if (tries == 7)
```

**In your main method**: -

```
System.out.println("\n Continue (y/n)? ");
choice = sc.next();
sc.nextLine(); --> // You don't need this line at all.. 
                   // It is just used to read user input.. 
                   // That you are doing in your `getIntWithinRange` method..
System.out.println();
```

**In your getInt method**: -

```
    else {
          System.out.println("Please enter a number... ");
    }
    sc.nextLine(); -->  // This should be sc.next().. And should be inside else
                        // You are just getting a new user input.. not required here..
                        // Just move the pointer to next input.. But don't read it..
```

Comment: Although it's not a direct answer, I still +1'ed this. Great answer.

Comment: @Austin.. Thanks.. Actually OP already got the answer to his question in previous answers.. I was just pointing some mistakes he might be interested in.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the extra input...  I'm a java noob

Comment: @TobinSherman. No problem in that, everyone starts from there only.. You will learn gradually.  :)

Comment: Ok so I got that situated but now my continue message is not working and having other problems with trying to get it figured out...  It's like it is disregarding the while loop..

Comment: Ok so I got that situated but now my continue message is not working and having other problems with trying to get it figured out...  It's like it is disregarding the while loop..

The code is exactly the same except I have my guess variable set in the class. I have a sc.nextLine() right above the if statements.. and the if statements are in a do while  with }while (guess != answer); depending on where I put the sc.nextLine() I get infinite loops, or varied results. Right now the code all runs except the continue option. When I type y it throws an exception. Its like its not even being read

Comment: oh jeez...  sorry  I have a "want to continue?" printline outside the do while loop... } printline"continue? y/n" choice =sc.next(); sc.nextLine

Comment: @TobinSherman.. Can you post your code what you are doing.. Update your post only.. It's hard to make a picture of what you are doing..